# passing the body of a function

Tags: racket

Is there a way I can pass in the body of a function rather than the name itself in Racket? For instance:

```
(define (foo x) (+ x 1))
(bar #'foo) ; I'd like to get #'(+ x 1) rather than #'foo
```

Answer (score 2):

**No.**

The source code of functions is not kept around at runtime in Racket. You might be able to accomplish something like what you want using some macro machinery, or even by implementing a custom `lambda` form that stores source code alongside the procedure, but without more context about what you’re actually trying to do, I don’t feel like I could give any more specific advice.

Comment: Context for Alexis' (IMHO) excellent answer: this kind of reflective feature can utterly destroy a compiler's ability to correctly optimize code. Some dynamic languages wave this kind of feature right in the front door and only later realize that it was a terrible idea. (To be fair, some other dynamic languages do this kind of thing with full knowledge of its implications. Protip: use languages designed by experts.) --- signed, an arrogant (but unapologetic) PL snob. :)